# Proto Shields wthout breadboard?

Tags: prototype

I want to use a proto shield (brand is unimportant) and solder some components to it, to make something more premanent than using a breadboard.

My question is can the components be soldered directly to the middle area where there are a lot of small holes?

I would assume this is possible, but everywhere I look people add mini breadboards to their proto shields.

If it's possible, then I assume components and wires can't just be connected in a row like on a breadboard and would instead need some solder between 2 holes where for example a component and seperate wire are connected?

Comment: You are completely right there. Just note that some proto-shield have some interconnected rows, just like a breadboard. But you can easily see that ([example](http://img.dxcdn.com/productimages/sku_65273_3.jpg))

Comment: Thanks Greben. Would upvote and accept if you posted as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different types of photo-shields, sometimes they have interconnected rows or they just have individual solder holes or even breadboards.  What you get all depends on what you are doing.  My personal favorite are the interlocked rows so I buy that and use a breadboard while I am developing my project then take off the breadboard and solder everything into place.

[Example of non interlocked rows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K992NTI)  and an [My favorite proto-shield, it has a little of both kinds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006SJSBBM)